# How to set mainClassName in Gradle 6.6 with modular Java

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, module-info

In Gradle 6.3 within build.gradle, mainClassName may be set like this with no complaints:

```
mainClassName = 'mod/app.Main'
```

In Gradle 6.61, the above line results in this:

> java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: Package mod.app not
> found in module

This can be resolved by removing the module portion of mainClassName:

```
mainClassName = 'app.Main'
```

While the exception is resolved, Gradle still states:

> No module was provided for main class, assuming the current module.
> Prefer providing 'mainClassName' in the following format:
> '$moduleName/a.b.Main'

I have experimented with variations of this:

```
ext.moduleName = 'mod'
mainClassName = '${ext.moduleName}/app.Main'
```

So far I have been unable to get any of these to work.  I could work with the setting as 'app.Main', but I would prefer to use the variation that Gradle prefers.  How should this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradle 6.3 doesn't support JPMS, but 6.4+ does. So I assume you are using the 3rd party [gradle-modules-plugin](https://github.com/java9-modularity/gradle-modules-plugin). For this plugin, you need to use version [1.7.0](https://github.com/java9-modularity/gradle-modules-plugin/releases/tag/v1.7.0) or later for supporting newer versions of Gradle.

Alternatively, remove the plugin and use the [native support](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html#sec:application_modular) in Gradle. Right now it looks like you are a mix of the two at the same time.

Comment: The plugins I am using are `application`, `javaFX 0.0.8`, and `jlink 2.22.0`.  I suspect that the javaFX plugin is providing JPMS support.  There is a newer 0.0.9 version available, but using this new version causes this: `org.joor.ReflectException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: javaExecHandleBuilder`.  Based on your answer then, is this likely an issue caused by the JavaFX plugin?

Comment: Actually the JavaFX plugin automatically applies the module plugin I linked to. But there is also an open issue on JavaFX relating to Gradle 6.6 (see [here](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-gradle-plugin/issues/89)) related to the ReflectException you mention. So you may need to wait until they fix it, or go with Gradle 6.5 in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

work in 6.3 `mainClassName = "$moduleName/app.Main"`

work in 6.4+

```
run {
    main = "$moduleName/app.Main"
}
```